# <A ng-href="#/about" tries to open /#!#%2Fabout on the browser instead of /#/about and fails

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, angular, angularjs

I am working on a single page angular web app using node.js as webserver to serve index.html

In index.html I have this ng-href tag:

```
<a ng-href="#/about">About</a>
```

I ran the following command on terminal to fire up node server

```
node server.js
```

index.html loads fine when I goto http://localhost:3000 or http://localhost:3000/# on my browser. But when I click on "About" button, a very weird issue is happening. It tries to open the escaped path http://localhost:3000/#!#%2Fabout instead of http://localhost:3000/#/about

What's even weird is that when I hover over the "About" button, in the bottom left of browser I see it resolves to http://localhost:3000/#/about. But when I click the button, the URL at the top is http://localhost:3000/#!#%2Fabout instead. Hence the About page doesn't show up. Why is my URL being escaped?

I have spent quite some time trying to debug this.

Comment: ...well, for the url, use maybe `encodeURI` ..

Comment: I didn't understand. This used to work 2 years ago. I cloned the repo and fired up the project and now it is misbehaving.

Do you mean I should do this?

<a ng-href="#!#%2Fabout">About</a>.      
I tried, same issue.

Comment: You can use <a routerLink="#/about" routerLinkActive="active">About</a>

you can have a look at this stackblitz demo :

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-routing-navigation-example-nhqexv?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: @ManishPatidar I don't see any clickable link there in the demo page you shared.

Also tried in my project, doesn't work. It doesn't even display the link when I hover over "About".

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vjw3tj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

You can see in the left bottom corner there you can see the path on hover of link